# Xamarin BLE how to increase characteristic array size and other questions

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the Xamarin BLE library implementation here: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

The characteristic array received is always 20 bytes. I need to do a file transfer from another device, so ideally I would like to receive and process larger packets.

I attempted to set the MTU, but the response was -1 which I assume means unsuccessful.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the maximum allowed data array size set?

Second question:
I also attempted to set the connection interval but the response there was false. I cant find much information about either in the repo docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
John

Comment: Writing/reading BLE characteristics are not designed for large transfers of data, you should do some BLE research and look at L2CAP

Comment: If you truly need to send more data over BLE you can always split it into 20 byte chunks and send them after another, but I agree that a larger MTU would be the better solution. Does your BLE device support a larger MTU? You can never set the MTU, its always a negotiation. The most fitting MTU for both sides will be selected

Comment: Where do you get "-1"?